# “thought of” vs “was thinking of”

Tags: prepositions, difference, gerunds

> *After she underwent her very first breakup she **thought of** suicide*.

and

> *After she underwent her very first breakup she **was thinking of** suicide*.

What's the difference between *thought of* and *was thinking of*?
And similarly what is the difference between *think of* and *thinking of*?

Comment: Here I guess past simple may suggest that perhaps she's not thinking of suicide any more.

Answer (score 1):

As expected the Simple shows a general idea whilst the Progressive shows the process.

When you "think of something" - you do it naturally, maybe often, maybe not, probably not now, but in general you do. When you are "thinking of something" - you are at it at the moment, you are in the process of it.

With the past it is the same. However, we can perceive the Past Simple "thought" as a single instance and thus render it as a process that occurred once in the past at a particular point in time.